# DAX - Summarize Daily Value Within Date Range

Tags: powerbi, dax, date-range, primavera

I need to convert the following sample of Activity ID with Start Date and Finish Date and Cost / Activity. I can calculate and get Activity Duration and Cost Per Activity Per day

Original table

[image]

Then I need to convert this shape to New table with Activity ID and Date in days and Cost / activity / date to this shape

[image: Table after modification]

To visualize the data as Cost and date S-Curve Primavera P6

Kindly share with me any paper related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Converting start/finish date combos is a little tricky in PBI. Because PBI doesn't see it as a date range/duration, just two independent scalar values. We can circumvent this with a measure though if the date table and the activity table are unrelated.

```
SUMX(activity,
    SUMX(
        DATESBETWEEN( 'Calendar'[Date], activity[start Date], activity[Finish Date] ),
        activity[Cost /Day]
    )
)
```

Then just create your visual with the date column of the calendar table and the activity column of the activity table. This will iterate over each activity and then each date within the activity date range.